# Python - selenium webpage open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scripting, webdriver

I have some code here that opens an existing webpage and clicks a button labeled "HTTP Ping". It opens the firefox browser but does not actually connect to the page or click the one button the page features. Any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.cloudping.info/")
element1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("HTTP Ping")
element1.click()
```

Now I'm receiving feedback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./finalProject", line 9, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/pjvaglic/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/home/pjvaglic/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pjvaglic/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pjvaglic/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 108, in _wait_until_connectable
    % (self.profile.path))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpTfjrqh If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Comment: What does the browser do instead of loading the requested page?  Does it do anything?

Comment: It will open the browser, wait a few minutes and then close. No errors or feedback.

Comment: I lied about the feedback. I edited it.

Comment: UPDATE: Managed to get the webpage to open and display by downgrading my firefox. Still having issues on pressing the button.

Comment: What versions of Firefox and geckodriver are you using?

Comment: the latest of gecko, firefox30